# Positive coefficients for lm() or gls()

Tags: r, statistics, lm

I wonder if anyone knows how to restrict certain coefficients in an `lm` or `gls` to be positive?

For example, I want `lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + ... + xn)` or `gls(y ~ x1 + x2 + ... + xn)` and I want, say, the coefficients of `x1` and `x2` to be non-negative.

Comment: Check the package `nnls` in `R` and the literature around non-negative least squares, I think this what you are looking for.

Comment: and also [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/61733/linear-regression-with-slope-constraint) should help.

Answer (score 3):

One option would be to use `nls(...)` which allows specifying upper and lower bounds for the parameters. So, something like:

```
# not tested...
fit <- nls(y~a*x1 + b*x2 +c*x3...,data=mydata, 
           start=c(a=1,b=1,c=1...), lower=c(a=0,b=0,c=NA,...), algorithm="port")
```

Read the documentation [here](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/nls.html).